# Using variables in sql code in python: Operation parameter must be a str

Tags: python, sql, variables

My goal is, that a user can make an input (which number he wants to delete) and this number will be then deleted.

As I try this, always the same error is appearing: Operation parameter must be a str

```
#Eintrag erstellen
if eingabe == "0":
eingabe_neu = input("Bitte Nachname, Vorname, Telefonnummer nach diesem Format eingeben Musterfrau, Mona, 793202277: ")
sql = '''INSERT INTO adressen (nachname, vorname, telefonnummer)
VALUES (?,?,?)''', [eingabe_neu]

cursor.execute(sql, (eingabe_neu,))
for dsatz in cursor:
    print(dsatz[0], dsatz[1], dsatz[2])
print()
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqcts.png)

Does somebody know, how I can fix this error and how I have to use variables in the sql-code?

Many thanks for help

Comment: Your code assigns a tuple to the variable `sql` but then uses `sql` in a context that requires a string. Drop `, [eingabe_neu]` from the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the parameter was a tuple of a list, where the list should be the tuple itself. It was getting a list instead of strings.

Can you try this one,

```
cursor.execute(sql, tuple(eingabe_neu))
```

If this does not work, please try this before the code above

```
eingabe_neu = [str(i) for i in eingabe_neu]
```

This is because all parameters must be string, currently, the data type of elements in eingabe_neu are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the particular error that you're getting comes from the fact that you write:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO adressen (nachname, vorname, telefonnummer)
VALUES (?,?,?)''', [eingabe_neu]
```

which makes your `sql` variable a tuple rather than a string containing a sql statement.

If you leave the `, [eingabe_neu]` out of the assignment, you shouldn't get that error. However, you will get others. Because `eingabe_neu` is still the raw input string that the user provided. You will have to convert it to a tuple of some sort with your values before you use it, e.g. like:

`eingabe_neu = tuple(eingabe_neu.split(", "))`

By writing `[eingabe_neu]` as you have done, you get a list with the first element being the entire string that the user provided, so each element is not the individual values you're after.

Your code should then look something like:

```
eingabe_neu = input("Bitte Nachname, Vorname, Telefonnummer nach diesem Format eingeben Musterfrau, Mona, 793202277: ")
eingabe_neu = tuple(eingabe_neu.split(", "))
sql = '''INSERT INTO adressen (nachname, vorname, telefonnummer)
VALUES (?,?,?)'''

cursor.execute(sql, eingabe_neu)
```

Can you give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

Many many thanks for the help of both of you.
It has worked with this code!

How do you make then the syntax in an sql-update-statement with variables?

As I know is the syntax for an update like this:

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET fieldname = value" "WHERE fieldname = value"
```

But if I try to use the code with two variables from an input, it doesn't work:

```
input_change = input("Write the number to change: ")
input_new = input("Write the new number: ")
sql = "UPDATE table SET telefonnummer = ?" "WHERE telefonnummer = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, (input_change, input_new))
connection.commit()
```